# Facebook graph api like fan page post as admin

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am using facebook graph api to like, comment, share on authenticated fan page.
The successfully implement comment on fan page. But when i try like status, i get error "(#100) The parameter url is required"

Following is code:

```
$params = array(    
   'access_token' => $token                     
);

$this->facebook->api('/'.$id.'/likes', 'post', $params);
```

Where $id is status id (576249592461805) and $token is valid token stored in database.

There are no permission issue because i successfully comment on this post:

```
https://www.facebook.com/1advertising/posts/576249592461805
```

I want to like this status via graph api..

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this?

```
$this->facebook->api("/$id/likes", 'post', function(response) {
if(response === true) {
    alert("done!");
}
});
```

Don't need parameters, qoute:

> You can write to the STATUS_MESSAGE_ID/likes connection to like the
>   status message by issuing an HTTP POST request with the publish_stream
>   permission. No parameters necessary.

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/status/

Comment: I tried following: $this->facebook->api('/576249592461805/likes', 'post'); but getting same error..

Comment: Without token, how will it know from which user its posting like??

Comment: Because you are using the publish_stream. I made a small change in my answers'code, try again. If it's not working please make sure you have publish_stream permission, https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/login/extended-permissions/

Comment: I had tried on https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer by pasting token and POST data on 576249592461805/likes then submit it. But getting same error that i get via api.. Permission is already granted (publish_stream, manage_pages, offline_access and some other)